# disabling edittext android using if else in view holder

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Please help me in succeeding my nightmare regarding on how to disable the editext using viewholder or another way on how to do it using `if and else` statement

I have a recycler view and it lists all names and their messages. (Messenger be like).  Somehow the recycler view consists of name ,message and a small tag textview “customer closed” if they will going to click the recycler view that consist of tag “customer closed” they will not be able to send messages because its already closed. Otherwise all recycler view that consist of a tag “customer closed” it’s editext is set in to false.

```
 public void bind(final Account account, final FirebaseChat chat) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            if (context instanceof NavigationActivity) {
                final Activity activity = (Activity) context;

                final Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), myChat.class);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_NEW, false);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT, account);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_CHAT, chat);

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    cName.setText(chat.getName());
    cName.setTypeface(chat.getReadCount() < chat.getNumMessages() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);
    cTextDate.setText(getFormattedDate(chat.getLastTime()));
    cTextMessage.setText(chat.getLastMessage());
    cTextMessage.setTypeface(chat.getReadCount() < chat.getNumMessages() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);



}




public void bind(final Account account, final FirebaseChatInfo customerInfo) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            if (context instanceof NavigationActivity) {
                final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), myChat.class);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_NEW, false);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT, account);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_CHAT_INFO, customerInfo);

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });




    cName.setText(chatInfo.getName());
    cName.setTypeface(chatInfo.isLastVisitorMessaged() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);
    cTextDate.setText(getFormattedDate(chatInfo.getLastTime()));
    cTextMessage.setText(chatInfo.getLastMessage());
    cMessage.setTypeface(chatInfo.isLastVisitorMessaged() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);

    this.shoptag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoptag);
    shoptag.setText(chatInfo.getShop_id());
    this.customerclosed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_closed);
    this.customerclosed.setVisibility(chatInfo.isClosed() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    this.message_editext = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_editext);

    message_text.setEnabled(!chatInfo.isClosed());

    if(customerInfo.isClosed())
    {

        message_text.setEnabled(false);


    }else {

        message_textt.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

i got this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is just add else tag

```
    if(customerInfo.isClosed){
        message_editext.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        message_editext.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: In a single line: message_editext.setEnabled(!customerInfo.isClosed);

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin  i also tried that code, but nothings happen , if am going to put the if else in view holder of customerInfo, unfortunately it will not recognize the message_editext, 
    because message_editext doesnt belong to the customerInfo holder , even if making the edittext protected didn't work :\'

Comment: @kris please provide full code of your adapter class.